# Show activity with contact list from sim card

Tags: android, contacts, sim-card

He
I would like to show activity with contacts from sim card.
Now I show list like this:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

but this way shows me only contacts from google account.

How to show contacts from sim card?
My program must run on android 1.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see this link ["How to access the sim contact table using the SDK."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208061/android-how-to-access-the-sim-contact-table-using-the-sdk) This is working though the solution is not part of the SDK.